# How to choose the package/folder when creating a controller with micronaut cli?

Tags: java, microservices, micronaut

To create a controller on micronaut cli the documentation say :

```
$ mn create-controller Book
| Rendered template Controller.java to destination src/main/java/example/BookController.java
| Rendered template ControllerTest.java to destination src/test/java/example/BookControllerTest.java
```

But my project has a well-defined folder structure for example:

```
| src -> main -> java -> com.myproject
                            -> domain
                            -> config
                            -> service
                            -> controller
```

per default micronaut will create the controller into the package com.project but i want to have my controller into com.project.controller.

How could we achieve it with the micronaut cli?

Comment: You are sure you want to package-by-layer, not package-by-feature? As I see it micronaut opts for the latter and because your service is a microservice (that only handles books) the structure would be `src/main/java/{package}/book`. with `BookController`, `BookService`, `BookRepository` and so on. Also: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

Comment: ok! lets say i adopt this approach. per default micronaut will add the BookController in the {package} folder. How to redirect it to /book folder?

Comment: I see! Just make `book` (the last) part of your package. (com.myproject.book)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set a default package per command. If you'd like you can file an issue and/or submit a PR to https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core